# How to link a cell to sheet reference

Tags: excel

If I type `Sheet2!A3` in `A1` Cell of Sheet1, it will show the value of A3 cell of Sheet2. But I want to use this reference link from a cell in Sheet1

[image]

Please, look at the snapshot. I want to use the `C1` cell to get the `Sheet2` part of `Sheet2!A3`. So If I change the value of `C1` from `Sheet2` to `Sheet3`, then the formula in `A1` will be changed to `Sheet3!A3`.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add in another cell to make things simpler

[image]

In Sheet2 A3 i have the Value 10

And these formula Get that value with just some simple Indirect reference

[image]

If you want to make A3 Dynamic as well then : [image]

The Aim is to get a cell which constructs the name of the cell/s you want to reference and then you can indirect Reference them accordingly.

Comment: A3 should be auto increment If I extend this formula to next cell/row. Here it is static.

Comment: I hope the Edit Answers your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Try: =INDIRECT($C$1&"!A" & ROW() + 2)

This will mean you can have any sheet name in C1, and it should be able to get whatever cell you specify in the quotes (don't forget the exclamation mark!)

EDIT: Sorry, I missed that part, I've updated it now and it should work to increment.

Comment: Thanks Clusks for your quick reply. Your formula worked well, but I also want to auto increment A3 of this formula if I extend this formula to next row. In this formula this A3 is static in case of extending the formula

Comment: I have updated the answer now, you can use ROW() to get the corresponding row, I've added + 2 to the row so it will get A3, and it should then be able to increment down.